# Temporarily set ENV variable for just one shell command?

Tags: shell, python, environment-variables

Is it possible to set an ENV variable for just one shell command (ie make it expire right after the command executes)?

For example:

```
export VERSIONER_PYTHON_PREFER_32_BIT=yes
winpdb
```

I'd like to set my system to use 32bit Python for just this command, then go back to 64bit.  Maybe something like

```
VERSIONER_PYTHON_PREFER_32_BIT=yes; winpdb
```

Thanks!

Comment: The `[python]` tag should only be used when the question directly relates to Python (e.g. it is written in Python). The same idea applies to tags in general.

Comment: I think the `[shell]` tag should be more specific (`[bourne-shell]` I assume).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

in Bash, you can do `VERSIONER_PYTHON_PREFER_32_BIT=yes winpdb` and the env variable is set for the command. Same as you propose but without semi-colon.

Comment: There's also the "`env`" command, which exists for exactly this purpose.  But yes, if you're already at a shell prompt, it's easier to just to "`ENV=foo cmd`".

Answer (score 1):

Run it in a subshell. so `(export VERIONSER_PYTHONG_PREFER_32_BIT=YES; winpdb)`

Answer (score 0):

Put parenthesis around the command:

(export VARNAME=value; cmd1; cmd2; cmd3)